# How to remove duplicate vertices and their vertex handles when performing hole filling in OpenFlipper based on OpenMesh

Tags: duplicates, indices, vertices, openmesh

Recently, I am using the plugin "hole filling" of OpenFlipper, and have entirely compiled the OpenFlipper. However, the new mesh has a large number of duplicate vertices, when I tried to add the filling patch to the original mesh. I used the following codes to perform the adding operation:

```
// filling_patch: newly created filling mesh
// mesh_ori: the original mesh before hole filling

class MeshT::FaceHandle fh;
class MeshT::FaceIter f_it, f_end;
class MeshT::FaceVertexIter fv_it;

for(f_it = filling_patch->faces_begin(), f_end = fill_patch ->faces_end(); f_it != f_end; f_it++)
{
   // ith face
   fh = *f_it;

   // Check whether it is valid
   if(!fh.is_valid())
   {
        return;
   }

   // Store its three vertices
   std::vector<class MeshT::VertexHandle> face_vhandles;
   face_vhandles.clear();

   // Iterate each vertex of this face
   for(fv_it = mesh_ori->fv_iter(fh); fv_it.is_valid(); fv_it++)
   {
        // Get the 3D point
        class MeshT::Point p = filling_patch->point(*fv_it);

        // Add this point to original mesh. Note: vh is a new vertevHandle, differ to *fv_it
        class MeshT::VertexHandle vh = mesh_ori->add_vertex(p);

        face_vhandles.push_back(vh);
   }

   // Save the face to mesh
   mesh_ori->add_face(face_vhandles);
}
```

So, I am not sure whether there is an existing function that can be used to fix this problem in OpenMesh.

Does someone give me some advice?

Thanks a lot.